# Discrepancies between R-package on github and install_github install

Tags: r, github, package, devtools, github-desktop

I am working on [my package](https://github.com/Ellesaere/tkis.package), which is hosted on github, using Visual Studio Code (1.67.1). I am using github desktop to push changes to the repository on github. This process works well. However when I re-install my package using:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Ellesaere/tkis.package", dependencies=TRUE, force=TRUE)
```

I often find that an older version is installed, even though the github repository shows the correct version. I cannot figure out what makes it work, or not work. This is getting extremely frustrating, as I continuously find myself restarting R, reinstalling the package, hoping that it installs the correct version this time.

I was wondering if anyone could give some reasons why this could be happening.

Comment: When using `devtools::install_github()`, are you installing from the right branch?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am always using the same line of code, and as far as I understand there, I have only one branch.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you had shared the GH link. Ok, only one branch. I wonder if this has to do with an older version being stored in another folder, which somehow takes precedence? Did you make any changes to `.libPaths` by any change?

Comment: You may also consider to increment your version number in DESCRIPTION.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Not knowingly.. I did change the directory, but I have removed all old files and updated the directory, using a pull request.

Comment: @tpetzoldt I am going to try this!